# Google Earth Engine,Selecting Image Properties

Tags: google-earth-engine

[image: ENgine]

Any ideas on how to select image properties:
In this instance, I want to mask all crop types except for Rice.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL')
              .filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
              .first();
var img_cropLC = dataset.select('cropland');
Map.setCenter(-100.55, 40.71, 4);
Map.addLayer(img_cropLC, {}, 'Crop Landcover');

print(img_cropLC)

var img_cropRice = img_cropLC.properties.cropland_class_names.select('Rice')
```

The last line is incorrect but I am looking for how to navigate into properties -> cropland_class_names -> and the select 'Rice'

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277220/filtering-image-in-google-earth-engine-based-on-metadata

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for this.

```
var img_cropRice = ee.List(img_cropLC.get('cropland_class_names'))

// knowing rice is at the third position:
var rice = img_cropRice.get(3);
```

[Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ccc1d8536e2c82883340c648daa34948)

Comment: Thanks for this. Yep, I was initially looking at how to select rice. But my overall objective was just to load only load the rice data and mask everything else. (I made another stack exchange post and figured how to do it based on the responses !)
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338475/google-earth-engine-creating-a-feature-collection-geometric-points